# Why is everything asked about referencing Report Viewer overlooked?

Tags: discussion

I have posted three or four questions today about using [Report Viewer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091.aspx) on my [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) web site. All together they don't have 20 views. Why is this?

I found another article that has over 700 views and no answer. My thoughts was this was a support forum and to come here for help yet all my questions are ignored. I'm guessing that's because the knowledge base of this topic is low to none considering the only person to help deleted his question... I am just curious why these questions are being avoided by readers?

Comment: I doubt the questions are being ignored.  Sometimes, just no one knows the answer..

Comment: @MikeChristensen it's very frustrating when you come here for help because you can't get past this and no help is given.

Comment: understandable, however realize that the people offering help are doing so during their own work hours or of their own free time.  there is no guarantee that you will get answers

Comment: Of course; programming is never ending frustration.  Keep in mind, people volunteer their help here.  You can't really expect too much from a free site.  If you feel entitled to professional coding help, *hire* professional coding help.  With that said, make sure your questions are *clear*, have all the information to understand the problem, including sample code to reproduce the issue.  If that *still* doesn't work, I suggest waiting a few days and then offering a bounty.

Comment: It may not be any help, but assuming you're talking about the .NET report viewer, http://gotreportviewer.com/ is a really good resource

Comment: @Gus thank you that was most helpful thing all day.

Comment: that section in grey on the right isn't ads.. it's downloadable examples that work.  Glad it helps!

Comment: If your questions are getting downvoted and deleted, you "should" be getting some feedback on 1) What's not jiving and 2) How to improve.  

To be quite frank, to @MikeChristensen point, it is free and the "currency" is the point system.  Make sure you're not asking someone to write your whole program for just the shot at 15 points.  Also often times the question is so specific to your problem that it's tough to answer.  Use a meaningful name and meaningful tags... I for instance have my SO filtered by specific tags, so I only ever see questions that are relevant to me.

Comment: [User Kpt.Khaos on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2992426/kpt-khaos) (most likely).

Comment: The report viewer is junk. It’s not quite worthless as you can still use it to render reports without using it in the page; but I've found that no one uses it who wants cross browser compatability. I have enough experience with the control to know that I will NEVER use it again and will opt for other, 3rd party, reporting products.

Comment: @Hardrada: Plus, writing reports in HTML is dead simple, especially with the binding tools that are now available.

Comment: @RobertHarvey true, but it also depends on what you're doing. For what I am working with, I MUST have PDF generation. Yes, I know there are tools that HTML=>PDF but it's not perfect. The one thing that SSRS gives me is that ability as much as it sucks. I am investigating third party reporting tools that can replace SSRS COMPLETELY. Additionally, there are some nice client side reporting JS libs and some libs (like sencha's) that do that plus a lot more for the type of reporting that you're talking about. Just depends on what you're doing.